# call to web api endpoint from same mvc application is timing out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST service implemented using ASP.NEt Web API. For some reasons I needed to call one of the endpoints from within the same application and report the time it took to get a response from the endpoint. For this added an normal MVC controller with an action as below

```
public class HealthMonitoringController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /HealthMonitoring/

    public ContentResult GetResponseTime(string id)
    {
        var startDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(<<REST endpoint>>);
        httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB");
        httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var duration = (int) DateTime.Now.Subtract(startDateTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        return Content(String.Format("response time:{0}", duration.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I'm using a `HttpWebRequest` class to invoke the REST endpoint hosted in the same website. I record the time before and after the request is made and return that time.

Problem

We have got a monitoring tool which calls on this route to get the recorded response time. The monitoring tool calls this route every 1 minute. This usually works for some time and then `httpWebRequest.GetResponse()` starts timing out for no obvious reason.There is nothing in the event log and in the IIS logs

At the point if I restart the application pool, this thing start working again for some time and then stops after some time.

While the above thing is not working, if I make the REST endpoint call myself manually, it works. So there is no issue with the REST endpoint.

I'm completely clueless at this point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a "health check" from the same domain is pretty irrelevant; and checking latency this way is especially trivial. Understanding you have problems and looking for a way to track this issue, use a trace log or elmah, not a repetitive ping to the endpoint.

That being said, if you want to check if the API is working you can instantiate the controller and call the method directly. This would test the *access* portion without layering the issue with potential socket trouble (`WebRequest`/`WebClient`/* libraries). Though you're not really getting in to delay, as I mentioned, delay is useless in this context anyways.

```
var api = new ApiController();
try {
  api.SomeMethod("param1", "param2");
  return Content("works");
} catch (Exception ex) {
  return Content("failed: " + ex.Message);
}
```